# How to round nullable decimal value when using System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, math, dynamic, dynamic-linq

When I try to use Math.Round(x,0) or  Math.Round(x) I get error `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: No applicable method 'Round' exists in type 'Math'`.

When I try to use Convert.ToInt64(x) I get exception `` Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.Object)' ``

When I try to use `(long)x` I get exception `No property or field 'long' exists in type 'DynamicClass1'`.

Comment: Can we see the code that raises those errors?

Comment: could you make your own method and check for ABS of Decimal Nullable

Comment: Line of code that gives exception looks like this: query.GroupBy("new(x as FieldName)","it"). I want to group by this field, but grouping by floating value gives too many group values, so I want to reduce number of groups by rounding it doing this: query.GroupBy("new(Math.Round(x) as FieldName)","it").

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Math.Round` requires a `decimal` not a (nullable) `decimal?`.

You could do something like this:

```
decimal?[] values = { 0.1M, 0.123M, 0.456M, 0.345M, null, 0.2M, 0.01M, null, 0.367M };

var grouped = values.GroupBy(x => x.HasValue ? (decimal?)Math.Round(x.Value, 1) : null);

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group {0} has these members:", group.Key == null ? "Null" : group.Key.ToString());
    foreach (var groupMember in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("> {0}", groupMember == null ? "Null" : groupMember.ToString());
    }
}
```

This retains the `null` values, mapping them onto a group with the key `null`. If you don't care about these, you could do something like this instead:

```
var grouped = values.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).GroupBy(x => Math.Round(x, 1));
```

so that everything will be non-nullable `decimal`.

Comment: As I mentioned, casting to (long) causes parse exception, so as casting to any other type including (double?). I already thought about that approach, but dynamic linq parser does not allow that. Dynamic linq parser is quite different than Linq, for example for conditional expressions it takes iif(expr,val1,val2) instead of C# ? operator. Basically, I don't know how to cast in Dynamic Linq.

Answer (score 0):

are you using a linq statement to do Math.Round(x,0); ?
if not it sounds like you would have to do System.Math.Round(x,0); aslo is x declared as a double or a decimal..? would need to see what your code actually looks like please..